# Couchbase Timeout but not logged in system:completed_requests

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am connecting to Couchbase from my spring-boot application : sometimes, I get timeouts :

[image]

But when I query for slow and timed out queries :

```
SELECT *
FROM system:completed_requests
WHERE requestTime BETWEEN '2019-06-18 20:00:00.000000000 +0100 CET' AND '2019-06-19 00:00:00.000000000 +0100 CET'
ORDER BY requestTime DESC;
```

I found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a definitive answer without knowing your completed_requests settings and the contents of system:completed_requests (and also your application side timeout) - but one potential explanation is that since we only store the last 4000 requests per node (assuming that you haven't changed the limit), the requests that had timed out have already been purged from the cache to make space for others?

Comment: Hi Marco i can guarantee you that is not the case.

Comment: could I see your completed_requests contents?